# google script to distribute the Column C data to C1:K1, Column D data to L1:R1 and so on . eight rows and six columns

Tags: google-apps-script

```
M1  TU1 WE1 TH1 FR1 SA1
M2  TU2 WE2 TH2 FR2 SA2
M3  TU3 WE3 TH3 FR3 SA3
M4  TU4 WE4 TH4 FR4 SA4
M5  TU5 WE5 TH5 FR5 SA5
M6  TU6 WE6 TH6 FR6 SA6
M7  TU7 WE7 TH7 FR7 SA7
M8  TU8 WE8 TH8 FR8 SA8
```

expection

```
M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8
```

column C data should get disributed to C1:J1
column D data should get distributed to K1:R1
and so on

Comment: What have you tried?  Its really quite simple.  First [transpose](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transpose-a-two-dimensional-2d-array-in-javascript/) then [flatten](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_array_flat.asp).

Comment: - [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, or anyone who writes code because they love it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We are not a script writing service.